# How can you obtain collection names of blend files in a specific folder?

Tags: python, blend-files

Hello I am currently trying to get collection names of blend files in a specific file without opening them. However I cannot find any resources around this topic. How can I achieve this?

What needs to be obtained:

[folder]

- blend1

  - **collection1** <--
  - **collection2** <--
  - **collection3** <--
- blend2

  - **collection1** <--
  - **collection2** <--
  - **collection3** <--
- blend3

  - **collection1** <--
  - **collection2** <--
  - **collection3** <--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the low-level API for reading the collection data block from each blend file.

```
import bpy
import os

# "//" identifier for the current blend file
folder = bpy.path.abspath("//")

# get all blend files in the folder
blends = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if f.endswith(".blend")]

for blend in blends:
    blend_path = os.path.join(folder, blend)
    # load the data from the file and print all collections
    with bpy.data.libraries.load(blend_path) as (data_from, _):
        # file name, list of collections
        print (blend, [c for c in data_from.collections])
```

Output:

```
b1.blend ['Collection1', 'Collection2']
b2.blend ['Collection2', 'Collection3']
b3.blend ['Collection4', 'Collection5']
```

Comment: This works as I needed it to be thank you so much!