# How can you update search enum list after changing it in different class?

Tags: python

Hello I am currently trying to have the search enum list update after changing the variable in the filebrowser. But whenever I change the variable in the filebrowser class, it does not update in the enum search list and remain the same. How can I achieve this?

**Expected output:**

```
search list:
    item1
    item2
    item3

after changing directory through filebrowser panel:

search list:
    item4
    item5
    item6
```

The search enum list is based on this code: [How can you obtain collection names of blend files in a specific folder?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253528/how-can-you-obtain-collection-names-of-blend-files-in-a-specific-folder)

example of my code is here

```
import bpy 
import os 
from bpy.props import (EnumProperty, 
                    StringProperty)

location = 'C:\Location' #initial location is required 

class search_local(bpy.types.Operator):

    global location

    bl_idname = "search.local"
    bl_label = "Search Local Assets"
    bl_property = "loc_search"

    items = ()

    blends = [f for f in os.listdir(location) if f.endswith(".blend")]

    for blend in blends:
        blend_path = os.path.join(location, blend)
        with bpy.data.libraries.load(blend_path) as (data_from, _):
            for c in data_from.collections:
                collitem = (c, c, "")
                items = (collitem,) + items

    loc_search: EnumProperty(
        name="Local Search",
        items = items,
    )               

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.loc_search)
        s = self.loc_search.split()
        new_set = str(' '.join(s[:-1]))
        file_path = str(location + new_set+' Collection.blend')
        
        inner_path = 'Collection'
        collection_name = self.loc_search
        bpy.ops.wm.append(filepath=os.path.join(file_path, inner_path, collection_name), directory=os.path.join(file_path, inner_path), filename=collection_name) 
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Selected:" + self.loc_search)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.invoke_search_popup(self)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

class folder_setting(bpy.types.Operator):
    
    global location

    bl_idname = 'folder.setting'
    bl_label = "Select Folder"

    filepath: bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype="FILE_PATH")

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object is not None 

    def execute(self, context):
        location = os.path.dirname(self.filepath)
        print(location) #debug purpose 
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, even):
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

class import_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "imp"
    bl_idname = "IMP_ID"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
       
        layout.operator(search_local.bl_idname, text= "Search Local Asset", icon="SORT_ASC")
        layout.operator(folder_setting.bl_idname, text="Folder Setting", icon="FILE_FOLDER")        
    
classes = (
    import_panel,
    folder_setting,
    search_local
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class 
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in classes:
        unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Hello, could you post your code ?

Comment: hello @Gorgious I have added the example version for my code in the update