# How can you obtain property information without executing it?

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to create a [list of blend files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253528/how-can-you-obtain-collection-names-of-blend-files-in-a-specific-folder) from a specific directory however I want to get the lists from a selected directory, which requires StringProperty to be used in the UI props. But in order to create a list, it needs to be initialized before `def execute(self, context)` but in order to get the information for the directory e.g. `context.scene.prop_tool.example_tool`, it requires it to be execute in the `def execute(self, context)` or else it returns the error calling `context` does not exist. How can I obtain the information for the properties without context?

example code:

```
class Properties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    items = ()
    mytool = context.scene.my_tools #this code will not run due to this context outside execute
    location = bpy.path.abspath(mytool.directory)
    
    blends = [f for f in os.listdir(location) if f.endswith(".blend")]

    for blend in blends:
        blend_path = os.path.join(location, blend)
        with bpy.data.libraries.load(blend_path) as (data_from, _):
            for c in data_from.collections:
                collitem = (c, c, "")
                items = (collitem,) + items

    local_search : EnumProperty(
        name="Local Search",
        items = items
    )
```

Comment: Please paste the text of your current code into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a string property to get the list, you can use a string constant and pathlib:

```py
from pathlib import Path

directory_name = Path(PATH_TO_DIRECTORY)
file_list = [file.name for file in directory_name.glob("*.blend")]
```

Will give you the list of blend files in the directory.

If you attach the directory name as a stringProperty, say DIRECTORY_NAME to something like bpy.types.Scene, you can initialize it in your `register` routine and give it a default value.  Then you can reference it as `bpy.context.scene.DIRECTORY_NAME` if you're not in a routine that has a context argument or `context.scene.DIRECTORY_NAME` if you are.

Comment: Sorry I should have added an example code the file lists are for addon panel search lists as seen in the link I put in the post

Comment: @KripC2160 You need to put your entire code into your question.  If you want to do file selection, you don't want to do it with a PropertyGroup, but with the [filebrowser](https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/using-blenders-filebrowser-with-python/) but without knowing how this all fits together, it's impossible to show you specifically what to do.